# En or ou d'or ?

Tags: prépositions

> Il était vraiment en or, son collier.
>
> Elle portait un collier d'or.

Pourquoi les différentes prépositions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*De* était autrefois la préposition qui s'imposait pour indiquer la matière mais *en* l'a supplanté. *Un collier d'or* est donc une aujourd'hui une expression recherchée, rarement utilisée en dehors des usages littéraires, poétiques.

En français courant, on dit toujours *elle portait un collier en or*.

Référence: [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2167)

Comment: Merci encore. Quelles références peux-tu me proposer pour le français courant ?

Answer (score 1):

**Translated in english:**
Her collar was made of gold

She wore a golden necklace

You could also say "Elle portait un collier en or", but then that would imply you insist on the material the collar is made of.