# What is the grammatical role of “de” in “un nouvel arbre d'or”?

Tags: prépositions, articles

I don't understand the role of "de" in this text. Is it a preposition or an *article indéfini* or an *article partitif*?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a preposition meaning "(made) of", i.e. a "a new gold tree".

See also [En or ou d'or ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30713/en-or-ou-dor)